# TabContent in react-bootstrap & componentClass props

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

I am trying to pass in a react component into the TabContents `componentClass` prop. This react component also needs to have props added to it. I am just wondering how this is possible.

I have tried something along the lines of

```
import MyClass from './somewhere';
import { TabContent } from 'react-bootstrap';
const x = <MyClass thing={y} />
..
..
<TabContent componentClass={x} />
```

but it does not work it seems that the TabContent class' componentClass propType requires elements or strings. I want to know what is the best way that I can pass in a react component that requires props that isnt a pure component to a tab pane...

Just for extra information. This component that I want to pass in fetches data from an API on mount or something along those lines.

Comment: So you don't want to render `MyClass` inside `TabContent`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to render `MyClass` inside of a `Tab`, which means i need to use `TabContent`, and the react-bootstrap documentation implies that I need to pass `MyClass` into TabContent's `componentClass` prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyClass` will inherit all props from `TabContainer`. So you can pass in the component as is and set the props you want to have there on the `TabContainer`.

```js
import MyClass from './somewhere';
import { TabContent } from 'react-bootstrap';
..
..
<TabContent componentClass={MyClass} thing={y} /> 
// MyClass will have `this.props.thing`.
```